# not sending the 500.html file res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/500.html'))

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

## This works on a macbook but I am presently using my windows computer. What am I doing wrong? Why is this not pointing to the 500.html file?

[image: 1]

i have tried many fixes I have seen on here and none of them work.
How can i keep my code relatively the same and fix the issue?